# no csrf token was found.issue with my rest api while sending csrf token and cookie in header

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee, resttemplate

## Background

I have to send some info like cookie and csrf-token(fetched from web application) as header to third party rest client using resttemplate.The way I am sending is as below:
I have set them in my yml file.

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("csrf_token", csrf_token);
    headers.add("Cookie", cookie);
```

## Snap of my postman req/res

[csrf issue postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt76F.png)

I am stuck here because with same token i am able to hit the rest client directly with postman but i am facing above issue with my own API which isinternally calling client using resttemplate.

what is the way to send the csrf token if my approach is wrong.

Comment: What's the correct value of the CSRF header? Generally speaking, Spring Security's built-in uses `X-CSRF-Token`.

Comment: actually the value keep on changing after every 24 hours and so.... for the vendor's application.

Comment: any lead on this issue??